# Cannot figure out how this procedure is meant to work, getting a weird error that I cannot understand

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to write a procedure that creates or replaces a view that makes use of a user-defined function that I have created. However, when I run the procedure, I keep getting the error:

> ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
>   ORA-06512: at "O015596H.CALCULATE_PAY_DUE", line 23
>   ORA-06512: at line 2

`CALCULATE_PAY_DUE` is the name of my procedure. It takes data from a table called `STAFF_HOURS`, and uses a UDF called `CALCULATE_STAFF_PAY`. I don't understand why it is looking for a table or view called `CALCULATE_PAY_DUE`?

I have tried running the procedure with both of these, but both produce the same error:

```
BEGIN
  CALCULATE_PAY_DUE;
END;

BEGIN
  CALCULATE_PAY_DUE();
END;
```

Here is the code for the procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CALCULATE_PAY_DUE
IS

STAFF_ID NUMBER;
FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(500);
LAST_NAME VARCHAR2(500);
HOURS_WORKED NUMBER;
MAX_HOURS NUMBER;
HOURLY_RATE NUMBER;
OVERTIME_RATE NUMBER;
WEEK_NUM NUMBER;
TOTAL_DUE NUMBER;
CREATE_VIEW_STMNT VARCHAR2(5000);

CURSOR C1 IS
    SELECT STAFF_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, HOURS_WORKED, MAX_HOURS, HOURLY_RATE, OVERTIME_RATE, WEEK_NUM, CALCULATE_WAGES(STAFF_ID, WEEK_NUM) AS "TOTAL_DUE" FROM STAFF_HOURS;

BEGIN

OPEN C1;
FETCH C1 INTO STAFF_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, HOURS_WORKED, MAX_HOURS, HOURLY_RATE, OVERTIME_RATE, WEEK_NUM, TOTAL_DUE;

CREATE_VIEW_STMNT := 'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW PAY_DUE AS SELECT * FROM C1';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE CREATE_VIEW_STMNT;

END;
```

Comment: Maybe you need to put a schema in front of it.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to SQL. What does this mean?

Comment: Actually I think the error appears to indicate it can't find `STAFF_HOURS`

Comment: I don't understand why that would be. Line 23 is "CREATE_VIEW_STMNT := ...", but I don't see what is wrong with it. I have added a line just below "FETCH C1..", and that seems to have shifted the error line to 25, which is the "EXECUTE IMMEDIATE...".

Comment: Why exactly do you want to use a function to create a View? What's wrong with a simple `CREATE VIEW` statement in plain SQL?

Comment: It's for an assignment where I have to demostrate usage of Functions, Procedures, and Triggers. The scneario I chose was to produce an MIS report for some fictional company. The function calculates a staff members' weekly wages based on their hours worked, hourly rate, and overtime rate, the procedure will put it in a view, and the trigger will fire the procedure every time a new timesheet is entered in to the main table.

Comment: I've never seen a piece of assessment ever bear any resemblance to a real life application. Including this one. Anyway: word of advice: those line numbers are always unreliable. The might start at the `IS` or they might not

Comment: @JohnYuki was that scenario actually listed as an option for your assignment? I don't think it's a good idea for a DML trigger to change a view. Why does it try to do this? The view should be fixed and you should just be able to query it for a staff ID. Your code example doesn't make any sense, as it fetches one row at random, attempts to modify the view using the results, and then stops.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson We weren't given a set list of scenarios to choose from. It was pretty open ended. We just had to demonstrate knowledge of functions, procedures, triggers, and use appropriate documentation. This is just what I chose. However, I was having so many issues with getting it to do what I wanted that I just came up with a different scenario that is simpler to implement.

Answer (score 1):

You try to create the view from C1. C1 is a cursor , this is not possible.

use instead:

```
CREATE_VIEW_STMNT := 'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW PAY_DUE AS SELECT STAFF_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, HOURS_WORKED, MAX_HOURS, HOURLY_RATE, OVERTIME_RATE, WEEK_NUM, CALCULATE_WAGES(STAFF_ID, WEEK_NUM) AS "TOTAL_DUE" FROM STAFF_HOURS';
```

Comment: I tried to do this but now it is giving me: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
ORA-06512: at "O015596H.CALCULATE_PAY_DUE", line 18
ORA-06512: at line 2. Line 18 is now my "EXECUTE IMMEDIATE" line.

Comment: Nevermind. I Googled around and found that adding "AUTHID CURRENT_USER" to the end of my first line works - and it did. Procedure now works as intended.

Comment: @JohnYuki To avoid the permissions issue without `authid current_user`, which seems a bit of a hack here, the owner of the procedure would need to have been directly granted `create view` privilege.